# how to change the redirect page on a paypal button via code

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal

Can I change the redirect-on-success page that a user gets redirected to AFTER paying with a paypal generated button from the code?

I have this code:

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sfdg@asdf.asdf">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="classes">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="99.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

Literally just a form with a paypal button on it.  Is there a way for me to set the redirect that button will go to after a user pays from the code?  Maybe another hidden field?

Comment: That seems to be a fairly crude way of handling PayPal... I am having trouble even finding the depreciated legacy documentation for that method. However you might have luck with passing `return_url` and `cancel_url` fields... might be `returnUrl` as well. I guess toy with it.

Comment: You should really look to using their js-sdk method which is the current supported way for all new integrations. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thank you and that does sound like the information I was looking for in the first comment, but where do I set those variables?

Answer (score 0):

The variable is called `return`, [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#paypal-checkout-page-variables).  So you would need to add a hidden input and set the value to the URL you want.

This type of form is a horribly old Web 1.0 integration, however -- really only supported by PayPal for backwards compatibility on very old websites.

Why not switch to [something modern](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)?

Comment: That may be a good thing to use, however I'm not sure why is new a better thing here?  Thank you, and I do see `return` documented on that page with a description that sounds  like just what I am looking for, but do I set that as an attribute?

Comment: from a brief look, your "something modern" link looks like it may have an easier solution to my problem so I may switch to that.  Can I add window.location.href = "url"; to the onApprove function?

Comment: Set the value attribute of a new input / Yes

Comment: In regards to 'why is new a better thing here'... I would say more control of data, better support, better security (LOL [I jest there](https://www.forbes.com/sites/zakdoffman/2020/02/25/critical-paypal-security-hack-multiple-thefts-now-reported-check-your-settings/)), easier to use once you figure it out. The issue with your form method is, anyone can change those variables and cause you headaches in processing later. A best approach is to use server side API transactions that both setup, verify, and capture orders. Keep javascript out of the equation.

Comment: wait, keep javascript out of the equation?  Isn't the "something modern" example from your answer javascript?

Comment: If you are able to make the necessary v2/orders API calls, there is a server-side pattern that gives more control: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Smart Payment Buttons does not use any redirection. After successful payment completion if you wish to do a redirect, that is up to you.

Comment: @PrestonPHX oh great, I am going to mark your answer as the solution, but before I do, is developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server backbonejs or what is the flavor of javascript that this more modern paypal integration is written in?

Comment: There is no server code on that page, it is the client-side UI only. There are two fetch() XHR calls to server endpoints, where you can use any language to implement the requisite v2/orders creation and capture. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ for details on those

Comment: How do I build a url so that the user is paying me and not the demo?  It appears that I have to replace the url from the demo: '/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/create/' but how do I build the new URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208582/discussion-between-ben-and-preston-phx).

Comment: Use any URL you want. It's your server.